# Fetch Phonecalls and PhoneImpression of adwords from google big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I am synching google adwords  data to google big Query storage system.
I am able to fetch keyword performance data by using following query for given date. But I want to fetch another two columns additionally  such as PhoneCalls and PhoneImpression, I tried joining with some of the tables. But, could not match the count with adwords portal report with query result. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT
  cs._DATA_DATE, c.ExternalCustomerId, c.Criteria,
  camp.CampaignName, adg.AdGroupName, c.ApprovalStatus,
  cs.Device, cs.AveragePosition,
  if ( SUM(clk.Clicks) != 0, SUM(clk.Clicks ), 0) AS PhoneCalls,
  if ( SUM( cs.Impressions ) != 0, SUM(cs.Impressions ), 0) AS Impressions,
  if ( SUM( cs.Interactions) != 0, SUM(cs.Interactions), 0) AS Interactions,
  if ( SUM( cs.Cost) != 0, SUM(cs.Cost/1000000), 0) AS Cost,
  if ( SUM( cs.Conversions) != 0, SUM(cs.Conversions), 0) AS Conversions
FROM `iso-gps.GLOBALPAYMENT.Keyword_XXXX` c
LEFT JOIN `iso-gps.GLOBALPAYMENT.ClickStats_9640337266` clk ON
  ( clk.CriteriaId = c.CriterionId
    AND c.CampaignId = clk.CampaignId
    AND c.AdGroupId = clk.AdGroupId
    AND clk._DATA_DATE='$Date'
    AND clk.ClickType ='CALLS' )
LEFT JOIN `iso-gps.GLOBALPAYMENT.KeywordBasicStats_XXXX` cs ON
  ( c.CriterionId = cs.CriterionId
    AND c.CampaignId = cs.CampaignId
    AND c.AdGroupId = cs.AdGroupId
    AND cs._DATA_DATE='$Date' )
INNER JOIN `iso-gps.GLOBALPAYMENT.Campaign_XXXX` camp ON
  ( camp.CampaignId = c.CampaignId
    AND camp._LATEST_DATE = camp._DATA_DATE)
INNER JOIN `iso-gps.GLOBALPAYMENT.AdGroup_XXXX` adg ON
  ( adg.AdGroupId = c.AdGroupId
    AND adg._LATEST_DATE = adg._DATA_DATE)
WHERE c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
ORDER BY cs._DATA_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Hi there, how are you exporting the data to BQ? You probably need to make sure you have the Ad Performance Report there (see all reports here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports )

Comment: I have na old Adwords script that I ran on a high level MCC to get these reports from Adwords. maybe you could use it to get what you need. See here: https://github.com/FKrauss/AdwordsScripts/tree/master/AWQLtoBQ

Comment: i have used following method to transfer the data , https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transfer  , which sync whole data structure of google adwords reporting portal

Comment: There's a schema here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/adwords-transformation search for `Ad Performance Report: Ad table`

Comment: You can only join them on Creative ID by what I can see here